# How add value to array textbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, textbox

How can I assign value to array named textbox?

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
```

Add values to Text box using jquery

```
$('input[name="amount[1]"]').val(20);
$('input[name="amount[2]"]').val(130);
$('input[name="amount[3]"]').val(50);
```

The above script is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** or **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

```js
$('input[name="amount[]"]').eq(0).val(20);
$('input[name="amount[]"]').eq(1).val(130);
$('input[name="amount[]"]').eq(2).val(50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
```

or

```js
$('input[name="amount[]"]:eq(0)').val(20);
$('input[name="amount[]"]:eq(1)').val(130);
$('input[name="amount[]"]:eq(2)').val(50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" />
```